# How to update a list of instance by counting the related item upon list?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to update a list of instances with the total number of books links to the category.

The response is as mentioned below. I have some books link to 'History' for example. How do I update the total number on the list whenever I call it?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category_name": "History",
        "category_code": "his",
        "is_tab": true,
        "add_time": "2020-03-02T15:56:58.469917Z",
        "total_number": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category_name": "Romance",
        "category_code": "ROM",
        "is_tab": true,
        "add_time": "2020-05-22T17:02:47.919479Z",
        "total_number": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "category_name": "Sci-fic",
        "category_code": "S-F",
        "is_tab": true,
        "add_time": "2020-05-22T17:04:57.896846Z",
        "total_number": 0
    }
]
```

serializer.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookCategory
        fields = ('id', 'category_name', 'category_code', "is_tab", 'add_time', 'total_number')
```

view.py

```
class BookCategoryDetailView(ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = BookCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

model.py

```
class BookCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name='Category name')
    category_code = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name='Category code')
    is_tab = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='is Navigate')
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Added time')
    total_number = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Total Number', editable=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Type Category'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        db_table = 'Book Genre'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

book model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    BOOK_STATUS = (
        ('Ongoing', u'Ongoing'),
        ('Completed', u'Completed')
    )
    book_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name='Book name', unique=True)
    book_image = models.ImageField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name='Book image')
    book_status = models.CharField(choices=BOOK_STATUS, default='Ongoing', verbose_name='Book Status', max_length=150,
                                   null=True)
    book_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    verbose_name='author',
                                    related_name='author',
                                    null=True)
    book_type = models.ForeignKey(BookCategory,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  verbose_name='book type',
                                  related_name='book_type',
                                  null=True)
    book_short_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Short description', default='')
    book_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Book Description', default='')
    # non-editable values
    total_words = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total_words', default=0, editable=False)
    chapter_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Chapter Count', default=0, editable=False)
    total_vote = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total vote', default=0, editable=False)
    weekly_vote = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Weekly vote', default=0, editable=False)
    total_click = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total Click', default=0, editable=False)
    fav_num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total favorite number', default=0, editable=False)
    added_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Added time', auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last update', auto_now=True, editable=False)

    def get_chapter_number(self):
        chapter_count = Chapter.objects.filter(self.id).count()
        return chapter_count

    def get_book_name(self):
        return self.book_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Books'
        verbose_name = 'Novel'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please do not store the number of `Book`s in the `BookCategory`, you can calculate that with the query (for all `BookCategory`s).

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated the model.py Thanks

Comment: @ThimothyShen: and the `Book` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi I have added it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common misconception is to give th [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) the same name as the relation itself. The `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so the relation Django creates to obtain the `Book`s from a given `BookCategory` for example. Therefore you can rename these to:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # …
    book_author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name='author',
        related_name='authored_books',
        null=True
    )
    book_type = models.ForeignKey(
        BookCategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='book type',
        related_name='books',
        null=True
    )
    # …
```

It is also better *not* to store duplicated (aggregate) data in the database, so storing the number of books is usually not a good idea. It turns out that keeping data in sync, even on the same database, is harder than one would expect. It means that if you create a book, delete a book, or change the category of a book, you need to update the count. Furthermore some removals will be triggered by other removals (cascading deletes), or by another tool than through the Django ORM, so that will only make the problem more complicated.

Therefore it is better to remove that field:

```
class BookCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name='Category name')
    category_code = models.CharField(default="", max_length=30, verbose_name='Category code')
    is_tab = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='is Navigate')
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Added time')
    # no total_number

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Type Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Type categories'
        db_table = 'Book Genre'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

You can obtain the number of books per `BookCategory` by annotating:

```
from django.db.models import Count

BookCategory.objects.annotate(
    total_number=Count('books')
)
```

This means that the `BookCategory`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_number` that contains the number of *related* `Book` objects.

Next we can update the serialzier to work with this `total_number`:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_number = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BookCategory
        fields = ('id', 'category_name', 'category_code', "is_tab", 'add_time', 'total_number')
```

and finally in the `BookCategoryDetailView` we pass the annotated queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class BookCategoryDetailView(RetrieveModelMixin, ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = BookCategory.objects.annotate(total_number=Count('books'))
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```